# How to exclude previously randomly selected NSArrays in loop

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, for-loop, nsarray

I'm new to Objective-C and I'm trying to create a simple dictionary style app for personal use. Right now I'm attempting to make a loop that prints randomly selected `NSArray`s that have been added to an `NSDictionary`. I'd like to print each array only once. Here is the code I'm working with:

```
NSArray *catList = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"Lion", @"Snow Leopard", @"Cheetah", nil];
NSArray *dogList = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"Dachshund", @"Pitt Bull", @"Pug", nil]; 
...
NSMutableDictionary *wordDictionary = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
[wordDictionary setObject: catList forKey:@"Cats"];
[wordDictionary setObject: dogList forKey:@"Dogs"]; 
...
NSInteger keyCount = [[wordDictionary allKeys] count];
NSInteger randomKeyIndex = arc4random() % keyCount;

int i = keyCount;

for (i=i; i>0; i--) {
    NSString *randomKey = [[wordDictionary allKeys] objectAtIndex:randomKeyIndex];
    NSMutableArray *randomlySelectedArray = [wordDictionary objectForKey:randomKey];
    NSLog(@"%@", randomlySelectedArray);
}
```

This code prints the same array "i" times. Any pointers on how to exclude previously printed arrays from being printed again?

I'm wondering if `removeObjectForKey:` could be of any use.

Comment: Is `removeObjectForKey` ok for you? That would remove the array from the dictionary.

Comment: I considered removeObjectForKey but wasn't sure how to implement it in the loop!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need to re-calculate the random key index every time you go through the loop, and then, as you suggest, use `removeObjectForKey:`.

Something like this:

```
NSArray *catList = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"Lion", @"Snow Leopard", @"Cheetah", nil];
NSArray *dogList = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"Dachshund", @"Pitt Bull", @"Pug", nil]; 

//...

NSMutableDictionary *wordDictionary = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
[wordDictionary setObject: catList forKey:@"Cats"];
[wordDictionary setObject: dogList forKey:@"Dogs"]; 

//...

while ([wordDictionary count] > 0) {    
    NSInteger keyCount = [wordDictionary count];
    NSInteger randomKeyIndex = arc4random() % keyCount;
    NSString *randomKey = [[wordDictionary allKeys] objectAtIndex:randomKeyIndex];
    NSMutableArray *randomlySelectedArray = [wordDictionary objectForKey:randomKey];
    NSLog(@"%@", randomlySelectedArray);

    [wordDictionary removeObjectForKey: randomKey];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In your code, you generate a random `randomKeyIndex`, then use it without changing its value `i` times in the loop. So you get `i` times the same array.

```
NSInteger randomKeyIndex = arc4random() % keyCount;
// ...
for (i=i; i>0; i--) {
    NSString *randomKey = [[wordDictionary allKeys] objectAtIndex:randomKeyIndex];
    // ...
}
```

As you say `removeObjectForKey` is an option for you, you can change your code into something like this:

```
NSInteger keyCount = [[wordDictionary allKeys] count];

for (i=keyCount; i>0; i--) {
    NSInteger randomKeyIndex = arc4random() % keyCount;
    NSString *randomKey = [[wordDictionary allKeys] objectAtIndex:randomKeyIndex];
    NSMutableArray *randomlySelectedArray = [wordDictionary objectForKey:randomKey];
    [wordDictionary removeObjectForKey:randomKey];
    keyCount--;
    NSLog(@"%@", randomlySelectedArray);
}
```

Comment: That's where I'm stuck @sch. I haven't been able to figure out how to change its value and also keep it random..

Comment: @OrpheusMercury - See the code at the end of my post, it shows you how to change the value of `randomKeyIndex`.